# Drupal autocomplete search UI bug

Tags: search, drupal, autocomplete, drupal-7

Hi in Drupal 7 I am using autocomplete search. In search input it displays part of ajax loader animation all the time even when the input is not focused. Bug is marked with red square [image: picture of bug] .

Any suggestions please why there is this bug. (I am using boostrap theme)

Thank you for help.

Comment: you sure that's ajax loader icon? all drupal autocomplete taxonomy reference fields have that circle for me. yours has some css issue, but i dont think its a bug that it is there

Comment: yeah i am sure it is a drupal throbber but somehow badly displayed. I just installed autocomplete module I did not modified any css from boostrap theme everything is as it was so I really dont know what is happening.

Comment: But when I try different theme it works good, so I guess there will be some conflict with boostrap

Comment: But I really do not know where, please any suggestions?

Comment: Ok I found solution, I went to css file inside module and commented line where there was set the throbber as background for input.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a twitter bootstrap error.

See your drupal installation's `misc/throbber.gif` file. You will see that it's actually a sprite and when the ajax request is in progress, it changes its position to show the animated throbber.

You will need to create a new one and adjust CSS accordingly to workaround this issue. Your text field has a relatively higher length than this sprite's

Add the following CSS to your theme's css file. These styles are defined already, so you will only need to override them. See inline comments.

```
html.js input.form-autocomplete {
    background-image: url("/misc/throbber.gif"); // Enter a new thribber image here.
    background-position: 100% 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

html.js input.throbbing {
  background-position: 100% -18px; // Adjust this -18px to the height of your new throbber. 
}
```